# USB speed converges to 0

Tags: 12.04, usb, laptop, usb-drive

I have a laptop and a desktop computer both running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I have an issue:

When transfer files from/to USB drives, the speed looks good when the copy starts, but immediately afterwards the speed goes down till a less than 1MB/s. After that, I just stop the operation.

I noticed the above with both PCs but only with some USB sticks. In general the USB filesystem is `FAT32` or `NTFS`.

*How can I solve this issue?*

Comment: Hi, my USB stick is " Kingston DataTraveler R3.0 G2". Is it a bad drive? I read that this stick is for single large files, I didn't expect that with small files  was so slow. However with Windows the average speed is about 30 mb/sec so I think that the problem is the OS

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So to have nice performance with ubuntu I have to pay more than 60$ for a stick? At this point is it better an hard drive?

EDIT If I change the filesystem of my pen from NTFS to exFAT, will I better performance?

Comment: can you answer my last questions?

Comment: why did you delete your last comment? Please answer my questions, I see that you are an expert. Wuold be important  for me

Comment: Good night.  I'm off to sleep...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem formatting my USB in exFat filesystem. If your pc doesn't find the drive, you will have to install `exfat-fuse` & `exfat-utilus` from `Synaptic Package Manager`

Answer (score 0):

What you're experiencing is the real write speed of cheap [MLC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-level_cell) USB sticks: The OS starts copying to the cache and then a background process starts copying from the cache to the USB stick.

Once the cache is full, the OS can only add to the cache *at the effective write speed of the USB stick*, so you will see this happening if you copy:

1. a single large file
2. a large number of small files.

Both of which exceed your cache.

*The only thing you can do about this is to use more expensive SLC USB sticks.*

Comment: As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**